# How to detect word boundary in regex for Arabic words - Python

Tags: python, regex, arabic

I am trying to remove any word that might contain non-Arabic characters. So, words like `ذهb`  or `word` should be removed.

I have managed to remove the non-Arabic characters using the below regex:

```
re.sub(r'([^،-٩]+)',' ', 'ذهb')
```

But how would I remove the whole word? Preceding the regex with `\b` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'\s*[\u0621-\u064A]*[^\W\d_\u0621-\u064A][^\W\d_]*', '', text)` or `re.sub(r'\s*\b[\u0621-\u064A]*[^\W\d_\u0621-\u064A][^\W\d_]*\b', '', text)`

Comment: @sin No any other language characters in Arabic words.

Comment: Not needed ? Deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'\s*\b[\u0621-\u064A]*[^\W\d_\u0621-\u064A][^\W\d_]*\b', '', text)
```

The `\s*\b[\u0621-\u064A]*[^\W\d_\u0621-\u064A][^\W\d_]*\b` matches

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[\u0621-\u064A]*` - zero or more Arabic letters
- `[^\W\d_\u0621-\u064A]` - any Unicode letter but Arabic letter
- `[^\W\d_]*` - any zero or more Unicode letters
- `\b` - a word boundary

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try ascii_letters. This should work.

```
import string

text = "".join([char for char in text if char not in string.ascii_letters]).strip()
return text
```

Comment: This removes the non-Arabic letters from the word, but the desired behavior is to remove **the entire word** if that word contains a non-Arabic letter

Comment: Yes, this is not what I want to do. I want to remove the entire word